# Hiding div depending on column value

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I need to hide the "Firm" div group if University Offer = "C" or "U". University Offer can also be "R" (Rejected) and "P" (Pending).

'

```
<div class="form-group">
@Html.LabelFor(model => model.UniversityOffer, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
            <div class="col-md-10">
                @Html.EditorFor(model => model.UniversityOffer, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.UniversityOffer, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="form-group">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Firm, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
            <div class="col-md-10">
                <div class="checkbox">
                    @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Firm)
                    @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Firm, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
```

'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try as follows:

```
@{
   if(!(Model.UniversityOffer == "C" || Model.UniversityOffer == "U"))
   {
      <div class="form-group">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Firm, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
            <div class="col-md-10">
                <div class="checkbox">
                    @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Firm)
                    @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Firm, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
   }

}
```

Comment: Worked perfectly thanks, would've taken me 2 seconds if it were PHP.